# Can I export Particle Fluid as VDB from Houdini?

Tags: simulation, particles, houdini, openvdb

I've created a scene in which water pours from a park fountain and I'd like to export the fluid simulation as VDB to import into Blender. Is this possible?

I've found the **VDB From Particles** and **VDB from Particle Fluid** nodes, but I'm not having luck exporting them in a usable fashion.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can export your VDB data in a *.vdb file per frame.
Blender has not VDB import yet, but [they are working on it](https://developer.blender.org/T73201).

Comment: In the recent 2.83 release, importing OpenVDB has been implemented now. However, isn't OpenVDB for volumes like smoke/fire, and not fluids?

Comment: Usually yes, but in Houdini nothing stop you from creating voxels from a flip sim if you ever want it